# Is it possible to make checkout page by yourself?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment, checkout

I tried to make that when click on buy it goes to stripe checkout page but,i need that if i change option to "exlusive" it change price only title and other stays same

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3cIx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM6YT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmaiH.png)

```
<section id="prodetails" class="section-p1">
            <div class="single-pro-image">
                <img src="img/Cover Arts/Autumn.png" width="100%" id="MainImage" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="single-pro-details"> <!--Fix in css-->
              <h6>Home / Beats</h6>
              <h4>Melodic Pop Beat = "Autumn"</h4>
              <h2 id="price">$5</h2>
              <select id="select">
               <option>Select Licence</option>
               <option>MP3</option>
               <option>Tagged Wav</option>
               <option>Un-Tagged Wav</option>
               <option>Stems</option>
               <option>Exlusive</option>
              </select>

              <script>
                let select = document.getElementById('select');
                let price = document.getElementById('price');

                // Prices
                let prices = {
                  "Select Licence": '$5',
                  "MP3": '$5',
                  "Tagged Wav": '$7',
                  "Un-Tagged Wav": '$10',
                  "Stems": '$15',
                  "Exlusive": '$50'
                }

                // When the value of select changes, this event listener fires and changes the text content of price to the coresponding value from the prices object
                select.addEventListener('change', () => {
                  price.textContent = prices[select.value];
                });
              </script>
            
                <!--<h2 id="sproduct-price">$25</h2>-->
                <a href="https://buy.stripe.com/bIYcNd7L051rag8cMN"><button class="normal">Add to Card</button></a>
                <h4>Product Details</h4>
                <span>Melodic Pop Beat - Autumn,Pop Beat in G Minor and BPM of 130,Beat is simple and melodic,It has the vibe of Dua Lipa and Weeknd Beat,The prices is great;just $5 for an tagged and mastered MP3,$7 tagged and unmastered Wav,$10 for un-tagged unmasterd and $15 for Stems,Exlusive are $50</span>
            </div>
            <div id="audio">
                <audio controls style="width:100%;"> 
                  <source src="Audio/Dua lipa 130 x Gmin.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                </audio>
              </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is set to go to a [Stripe Payment Link](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links), which is a reusable link that will always charge someone for the same thing.

If you want people to be able to purchase different things you need to create different Payment Links for the different options, then adjust your page so it sends them to the right Payment Link based on what they want to buy.